# Converting From Minutes to Milliseconds, then to Int

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to run the following conversion, which results in an invalid cast exception

> specified cast is not valid

```
settings.ActionTimer = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)ActionTimerComboBox.SelectedValue).TotalMilliseconds);
```

What this is attempting is the following:

1. Take the value of `ActionTimerComboBox.SelectedValue`, which in this case is "13" and convert it from object to double so that TimeSpan.FromMinutes() can be applied to it.
2. Convert "13 minutes" to milliseconds.
3. Update int `settings.ActionTimer` to the millisecond converted value, which should be "780000".

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks fine except the conversion from `ActionTimerComboBox.SelectedValue` to double. And that's the error message also saying. you have to use something like the following:

```
string comboSelectedValue = ActionTimerComboBox.SelectedValue;
double selectedVal =0.0;
if(double.TryParse(comboSelectedValue, out selectedVal)){
    settings.ActionTimer = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(selectedVal).TotalMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(selectedVal).TotalMilliseconds);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error in conversion");
}
```

Working Example [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fhkKjI). This [Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/type-casting-in-c-sharp) may helps you to know more about type casting.

Answer (score 2):

ActionTimerComboBox.SelectedValue is returning string you can't cast it as double,
you should try double.Parse(), double.TryParse() Or Convert class as you used here.
-sorry couldn't comment

Answer (score 0):

This exception is coming from this statement:

```
((double)ActionTimerComboBox.SelectedValue)
```

Object to Double conversion is throwing invalid cast exception.
Either convert this object to string first and then convert it to double.

```
((double)ActionTimerComboBox.SelectedValue.toString());
```

Or, You can also use below code:

```
var val = ActionTimerComboBox.SelectedValue;
if (val is IConvertible)
{
 double d = ((IConvertible)val).ToDouble(null);
}
```